# how to use a class in a function parameter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

please help, im designing a contact book as a project and i'm having compiling the code properly and im getting errors. problem in relation to Address class.. feel free to copy and run code to see what im talking about. thanks in advance

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    class Address
    {
   private:
      string home;
      string street;
      string apt;
      string city;
      string state;
      string zip;

   public:

      Address();

     string getHome() const;
    string getStreet() const;

      string getApt() const;

      string getCity() const;

      string getState() const;

      string getZip() const;

      void output() const;

      void input();
};

class contact{
private:
    string fn;  
    string ln;
    Address address;
    string email;
    string number;
public:
    void input();
    void output();
    void setname(string f_n, string l_n);
    void setaddress(Address home);
    void setemail(string emaila);
    void setnumber(string num);
    string getname();
    string getAddress();
    string getemail();
    string getnumber();

contact();
contact(string f_n, string l_n, Address home,string emaila,string num);

};
void menu(string opt);
int main(){
        string opt="";
     contact c;
     c.input();
     menu(opt);
     c.output();

cout<<"input up to 10 contacts, type quit to stop if less than 10: "<<endl;

return 0;
}
void menu(string opt){
cout<<"Choose(type) a Menu: search | display all(show) | exit'"<<endl;
cin>>opt;
if(opt=="search")cout<<"write a function that index"<<endl;
else if(opt=="show")cout<<"write a function that display all: "<<endl;
else if(opt=="exit")exit(0);
}
contact::contact(){ 
    fn="";  ln="";  Address address;    email="";   number="";
}
contact::contact(string f_n, string l_n, Address address,string emaila,string num){
fn= f_n; ln= l_n; address ="" ;email= emaila;number= num;
}

void contact::input(){
 for (int i=1; i<=10;i++){//allow 10 contacts
cout<<"fn and ln separate by a space: ";
cin>>fn>>ln;
cout<<"address: ";
Address.input();
cout<<"email: ";
cin>>email;
cout<<"phone number: ";
cin>>number;
}
}
void contact::output(){
cout<<"name: "<<fn<<" "<<ln<<" address "<<Address.output();<<" email: "<<email<<"         digits "<<number<<endl;
}
void contact::setname(string f_n, string l_n){
fn= f_n; ln= l_n;
}

void contact::setemail(string emaila){
email= emaila;
}
void contact::setnumber(string num){
number= num;
}
string contact::getAddress(){
return Address address;
}
string contact::getname(){
return fn, ln;
}

string contact::getemail(){
return email;
}
string contact::getnumber(){
return number;
}
```

Comment: *"feel free to copy and run code to see what im talking about"* -- You'll really let me do that?  Gee, thanks mister!!

Comment: Please post your errors - it's far easier for most people.

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: Reducing your code to a minimal example that produces the same error is key. It will make it easier for us to look at your code and see what's wrong with it, and it will also help you to clear away all the extra stuff you've been looking at in order to focus on the problem, which may help you fix it yourself. And even if you can't, it certainly shows us that you tried. No one wants to wade through a lot of extraneous code to find errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the output of your code when run through clang (for its far nicer messages).

```
λ > clang++ blah.cxx 
blah.cxx:81:27: error: no viable overloaded '='
fn= f_n; ln= l_n; address ="" ;email= emaila;number= num;
                  ~~~~~~~ ^~~
blah.cxx:5:11: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [1]' to 'const Address' for 1st argument
```

The above means you can't do this: `address = ""`, because you don't have any implicit conversions from a `const char*` to an `Address` object.

You probably meant `this->address = address`, since it seems like you'd want to assign the `address` you received in the constructor?

As a side note, depending on the compiler you use, you might want to pass `Address address` by reference like `Address& address` or `const Address& address` (indicating you won't modify the object being referenced) in your function argument list. Though some compilers (if not the most widely used ones) will implement the [copy ellision optimization](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

For example your constructor arguments would look like this:

```
contact(string f_n, string l_n, const Address& home,string emaila, string num);
```

---

```
    class Address
          ^
blah.cxx:89:8: error: expected unqualified-id
Address.input();
       ^
blah.cxx:97:43: error: 'Address' does not refer to a value
cout<<"name: "<<fn<<" "<<ln<<" address "<<Address.output();<<" email: "<<email<<"         digits "<<number<<endl;
                                          ^
```

Your member object is called `address`, not `Address`. You want to call `address.output()`, otherwise `Address.output()` is really trying to call a [`static` function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr039.htm) called `output` from the `Address` class.

---

```
blah.cxx:97:60: error: expected expression
cout<<"name: "<<fn<<" "<<ln<<" address "<<Address.output();<<" email: "<<email<<"         digits "<<number<<endl;
```

Same problem as above, use `address.output()` since you're calling the function `output()` on `address`.

---

```
blah.cxx:110:8: error: 'Address' does not refer to a value
return Address address;
       ^
```

`return address;` is the correct way to return the `address` object. `return Address address;` is nonsense.

---

```
blah.cxx:113:8: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
return fn, ln;
       ^~
1 warning and 5 errors generated.
```

`fn` is unused here. Just a warning, but it indicates you either forgot to use it, or it can be removed from your code without harm.

Comment: Nice answer. Also I would mention passing objects as parameters by reference, not by value

Comment: @Andrey - threw a description in at the top error, along with a link to possibly compiler optimizations with copy ellision.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code, the error seems to be at the following places (I haven't compiled your code)

```
contact::contact(string f_n, string l_n, Address address,string emaila,string num){
fn= f_n; ln= l_n; address ="" ;email= emaila;number= num;
}
```

When you do

```
address ="";
```

You haven't overloaded = operator to set address to an empty string. It is invalid.

You must overload "=" operator to set each member of the Address class to an empty string.

Try something like this:

```
Address operator=(string str)
{
  this.home = str;
  this.street = str;
  this.apt = str;
  this.city = str;
  this.state = str;
  this.zip = str;
}
```

in your input() function:
    Address.input();

you cannot use a class to invoke a function directly unless you make the function static.
You should use:

address.input();

similarly. instead of

```
Address.output();
```

use

```
address.output();
```

Another error must be here:

```
return Address address;
```

You do not return pointers like this.
Just imagine how would you return a char pointer.
For example if you have:

```
char *a;
```

then suppose in a function:

```
(char*) test()
{
  return a; //notice not "return char a"
}
```

similarly in your code, you should return the object and not the class type.
i.e.

```
return address; //not return Address address
```